# Does Python raise TypeErrors before short-circuiting a boolean?

Tags: python, short-circuiting, typechecking

I have a function that performs a monthly task on one or more specified days (e.g., the first and the 15th.)  For enhanced usability, I want to let users just pass in a single int when they only want it to happen one day each month, or a list of ints for multiple events per month.

```
monthly_event(days_of_month=1, event="paycheck") 
monthly_event(days_of_month=[1,15], event="bills", starting=date(2013,1,1))
```

Internally the function will iterate over the list and do the same thing it would do for a single int.

Since "int" is not an iterable, I need to do something to avoid a TypeError when the user just passes a single int.  I was surprised to find that using an "or" expression and relying on short-circuiting does not work - the TypeError still happens.  Here's an example:

```
from datetime import date as date
dt = date.today()
days = 1
#days = [1,2]
if dt.day == days or dt.day in days:
    print "GOOD"
else:
    print "BAD"
```

My first question is:  have I misunderstood Python, or does the internal typecheck really happen on the entire line of code before the short-circuiting of the boolean expression?  That seems very strange.

My second question is:  what is the Pythonic way to do this?  I'd like to avoid doing an explicit type check on the "days" variable.  Using a try/catch instead just bloats the code:

```
try:
    if dt.day == days:
        print "GOOD"
    else:
        print "BAD"
except TypeError:
    if dt.day in days:
        print "GOOD"
    else:
        print "BAD"
```

Is there something obvious I've overlooked?

Comment: `days = days if hasattr(days, "__iter__") else [days]`

Comment: or: `import collections; days = days if isinstance(days, collections.Iterable) else [days]`

Comment: Just require `days_of_month` to always be an iterable (as its name suggests!). If the caller only wants one day, they can pass in a one-tuple or a list or set with length one or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem occurs when `dt.day != days` (and the short circuit is not taken), Python will then try the `dt.day in days` expression, and get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Ugh - that's kind of embarrassing.  Thanks.